# Mac API to get current media playing

Tags: objective-c, macos, media

On the mac you can use their native 'f-keys' to do things like change volume, brightness, and even pause or play music or video.

I was wondering if there was someway to access to 'now playing' media (music or video) through an API or something?

I know it's possible to get currently playing tracks from iTunes using things like `ITLibMediaItem` or even from other apps by using `Applescript` to ask the application what it's header is. But how would you figure out which application is the 'currently playing' one and then get the play pause functionality?

Does Apple have an API for this?

Comment: "Now playing" as in checking if any sound at all is being run through the speakers, or "now playing" like iTunes?

Comment: 'Now playing' as in it can be played/paused/skipped using [these](http://www.freakified.net/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/IMG_3871.jpg) keys. Plan to use the feature so I can get the song's information